# Pycharm detection

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to know whether python script is started from PyCharm. Next string

```
 in_pycharm = 'original_argv' in dir(sys) and 'pydevd' in sys.original_argv[0]
```

works ok for Debug and don't work for Run.
Can anyone recommend me better way?

Comment: Why is it important to know where the script was started from? Could this be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: With Linux running `ps aux` you'll be able to see the parent process, maybe you can use that in some way.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is probably to have pycharm specify an environment variable, something like `INPYCHARM=1`, then check `os.environ.get('INPYCHARM')==1`.  You can specify the environment variable in the Run/Debug configuration menu (from the Run drop-down menu).

Edit:  Looks like `PYCHARM_HOSTED` is specified in `os.environ` by default, so the following should work (tested on pycharm 5.0.4).

```
in_pycharm = 'PYCHARM_HOSTED' in os.environ
```